# How to use OkHttp Library for providing spdy support to android client?

Tags: android, client-side, spdy, okhttp

I want to make a simple app of an android client with Speedy (SPDY) support, but I am really stuck.

I am using the v2.0.0 JAR of OkHttp in the app that I am making. I used the following code (taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/GetExample.java)):

```
package com.squareup.okhttp.guide;

import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GetExample {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GetExample example = new GetExample();
    String response = example.run("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md");
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

The `nextCall()` method here does not get executed.  It repeatedly says that the `nextCall()` method does not exist in the `OkHttpClient` class.

Comment: I am using the v2.0.0 JAR of OkHttp in the app that I am making. I used the following code :- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/guide/GetExample.java                                      The nextCall() method here does not get executed.

Comment: It repeatedly says that the nextCall() method does not exist in the OkHttpClient class.

Comment: Where is this nextCall() method in your code? Also be sure you included okio, download from here [link](http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.squareup.okio&a=okio&v=LATEST)

Which is stated [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/#download)

Comment: It's newCall, not nextCall.